# Manually provide the number of steps to be executed by a drive (RepRap firmware 3.3)

Tags: reprap-firmware

I am writing an M-code for a new algorithm to reduce vibrations during printing. After a bit of preprocessing, my algorithm spits out the number of steps for each drive. Is there any way I can provide these steps directly to the drives to be executed?

E.g. instead of providing `G0 X5`I would like to send `Some_G_code X400` which basically says the x drive should move 400 steps which would result in the same move as `G0 X5`, assuming 80 steps/mm.

Comment: Have you tried setting steps per mm to 1?

Comment: How is this going to work when you need to be coordinating motions of multiple motors in sync?

Comment: @Mick I can't do that since I do not want my input (400 in the eg) to go through any segmentation preprocessing etc. I would just like to give it as a command to the stepper drivers.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE they will be provided to the stepper driver in the same order as to maintain the step time order

Comment: @HDEV5: Just knowing order lacks sufficient information to control the relative timing. You should probably look at how Klipper does this.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Could you provide me a link for reading?